# Play a DRM protected video using FPS in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, drm, fairplay

I'm developing an iOS application, which has web views inside it. Videos are getting played inside the web view. However, some of the videos are DRM protected and not being played in web view. Please help me out in playing those videos. I have referred FairPlay Streaming notes but unable to get anything out of it. All help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Fairplay is not supported in Safari on ios at this time.  You need to use a native ios application with a video player like AVFoundation to use fairplay on ios.